# Google sheets script if function with several criteria

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use a script in which I have a line with the IF function that says: If in column 21 of the tab "Suivi Clients" there are the values "OUI" or "ANNULÉ", then the function executes.

```
if (sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' && rng.getColumn() == 21)  {
    if (rng.getValue() == 'OUI' || rng.getValue() == 'ANNULÉ') {
```

I would like to modify to say: If in the column 21 AND column 12 of the tab "Suivi Clients" there are the values "OUI" or "ANNULÉ", then the function executes.

I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
if (sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' && rng.getColumn() == 12 && rng.getColumn() == 21)  {
    if (rng.getValue() == 'OUI' || rng.getValue() == 'ANNULÉ') {
```

The sheets is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CPcMx3Dhbqi-zO4D3jYNxO-PGjyW3iTfRo5gRmEB9p4/edit#gid=0

The complete code to modify is here:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if (sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' && rng.getColumn() == 21)  {
    if (rng.getValue() == 'OUI' || rng.getValue() == 'ANNULÉ') {

      var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Clients Finalisé')
      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      var plage = sh.getRange('C' + rng.getRow() + ':G' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('L' + rng.getRow() + ':N' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('U' + rng.getRow() + ':W' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortCF()
    }
  }

  if (sh.getName() == 'Clients Finalisé' && rng.getColumn() == 12 || rng.getColumn() == 21) {
    if (rng.getValue() == 'NON') {

      var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Suivi Clients')
      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      var plage = sh.getRange('C' + rng.getRow() + ':G' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('L' + rng.getRow() + ':N' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('U' + rng.getRow() + ':W' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortSC()
    }
  }

  if (sh.getName() != 'Suivi Clients') return;
  var editRange = {
    top: 6,
    left: 3,
    right: 7
  };
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;
  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;
  removeEmpty()
}

function sortSC() { // Suivi Clients
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Suivi Clients");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({ column: 7, ascending: true });
}

function sortCF() { // Clients Finalisé
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients Finalisé");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({ column: 16, ascending: true });
}

Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function (col) {
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  if (col == null) { col = 1 }
  var range = this.getRange(lastRow, col);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }
};
```

The complete code that works is here:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  var rngRow = rng.getRow();
  var rngCol = rng.getColumn();

  if (sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients') {
    var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Clients Finalisé');
    var otherCol = sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' ? rngCol == 12 ? 21 : 12 : '';
    var [cell, otherCell] = sh.getRangeList([`R${rngRow}C${rngCol}`, `R${rngRow}C${otherCol}`])
      .getRanges().map(range => range.getValue());

    if ((cell == 'OUI' || cell == 'ANNULÉ') && (otherCell == 'OUI' || otherCell == 'ANNULÉ')) {

      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      sh.getRangeList([`C${rngRow}:G${rngRow}`, `L${rngRow}:N${rngRow}`, `P${rngRow}`, `U${rngRow}:W${rngRow}`])
        .getRanges().forEach(range => range.copyTo(dest.getRange(`${range.getA1Notation()[0]}7`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false))

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortCF()
    }

  } else if (sh.getName() == 'Clients Finalisé') {
    var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Suivi Clients');
    var otherCol = sh.getName() == 'Clients Finalisé' ? rngCol == 12 ? 21 : 12 : '';
    var [cell, otherCell] = sh.getRangeList([`R${rngRow}C${rngCol}`, `R${rngRow}C${otherCol}`])
      .getRanges().map(range => range.getValue());
      
    if ((cell == 'NON') || (otherCell == 'NON')) {

      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      sh.getRangeList([`C${rngRow}:G${rngRow}`, `L${rngRow}:N${rngRow}`, `P${rngRow}`, `U${rngRow}:W${rngRow}`])
        .getRanges().forEach(range => range.copyTo(dest.getRange(`${range.getA1Notation()[0]}7`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false))

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortSC()
    }
  }  

  if (sh.getName() != 'Suivi Clients') return;
  var editRange = {
    top: 6,
    left: 3,
    right: 7
  };
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;
  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;
  removeEmpty()
}

function sortSC() { // Suivi Clients
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Suivi Clients");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({ column: 7, ascending: true });
}

function sortCF() { // Clients Finalisé
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients Finalisé");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({ column: 16, ascending: true });
}

Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function (col) {
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  if (col == null) { col = 1 }
  var range = this.getRange(lastRow, col);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }
};
```

Comment: is this part of an onEdit() trigger?

Comment: yes, it is.....

Comment: Each question should be self-contained. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Please share an example or copy of your spreadsheet. Remove sensitive data if any. See comment posted by Rubén. Also what exactly are you trying to do, what is the expected result? Would help us replicate and provide you with a solution or suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill. In the current stage, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I have to study English more.

Comment: I would like the conditions in the "Suivi Clients" tab to be "OUI" or "ANNULÉ" in the L AND U column so that the rows go from "Suivi Clients" to "Clients Finalisé". This would mean that the customer's file is paid or cancelled, so it is finished.

Comment: Once a customer's row is in the "Clients Finalisé" tab, I would like that if I change the value of the L OR U column from "OUI" or "ANNULÉ" to "NON", the row goes back to the "Suivi Clients" tab. This would mean that the customer has decided not to cancel anymore or that there was a problem with the payment and therefore the file is not completely finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  var rngRow = rng.getRow();
  var rngCol = rng.getColumn();

  var dest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Clients Finalisé');

  var otherCol = sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' ? rngCol == 12 ? 21 : 12 : '';
  var [cell, otherCell] = sh.getRangeList([`R${rngRow}C${rngCol}`, `R${rngRow}C${otherCol}`])
                              .getRanges().map(range => range.getValue());

  if ((cell == 'OUI' || cell == 'ANNULÉ') && (otherCell == 'OUI' || otherCell == 'ANNULÉ')) {

    dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      sh.getRangeList([`C${rngRow}:G${rngRow}`, `L${rngRow}:N${rngRow}`, `P${rngRow}`, `U${rngRow}:W${rngRow}`])
      .getRanges().forEach(range => range.copyTo(dest.getRange(`${range.getA1Notation()[0]}7`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false))

    sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    sortCF()
    
  }
};
```

The reason why your code did not work was because of `rng.getColumn() == 12 && rng.getColumn() == 21` since you are using an onEdit() and you are only editing at one cell so technically it can only be either column 12 or column 21.

In the codes I've added a var to determine the other column so you have a hold of both columns. You can now check the cell and otherCell if it is either 'OUI' or 'ANNULÉ'.

Also for the script to copy multiple range, it uses too much line for repetitive codes so I tried to make it shorter.

Let me know if this works!

Here's the reference on how to copy multiple ranges:
[Apps script copy multiple range from 1 sheet to another spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199164/apps-script-copy-multiple-range-from-1-sheet-to-another-spreadsheet)

### EDIT - Added codes

As your comment stated:

> Once a customer's row is in the "Clients Finalisé" tab, I would like
> that if I change the value of the L OR U column from "OUI" or "ANNULÉ"
> to "NON", the row goes back to the "Suivi Clients" tab.

I have added the codes for this. Try the updated codes below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  var rngRow = rng.getRow();
  var rngCol = rng.getColumn();

  if (sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients') {
    var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Clients Finalisé');
    var otherCol = sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' ? rngCol == 12 ? 21 : 12 : '';
    var [cell, otherCell] = sh.getRangeList([`R${rngRow}C${rngCol}`, `R${rngRow}C${otherCol}`])
      .getRanges().map(range => range.getValue());

    if ((cell == 'OUI' || cell == 'ANNULÉ') && (otherCell == 'OUI' || otherCell == 'ANNULÉ')) {

      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      sh.getRangeList([`C${rngRow}:G${rngRow}`, `L${rngRow}:N${rngRow}`, `P${rngRow}`, `U${rngRow}:W${rngRow}`])
        .getRanges().forEach(range => range.copyTo(dest.getRange(`${range.getA1Notation()[0]}7`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false))

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortCF()
    };

  } else if (sh.getName() == 'Clients Finalisé') {
    var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Suivi Clients');
    var otherCol = sh.getName() == 'Clients Finalisé' ? rngCol == 12 ? 21 : 12 : '';
    var [cell, otherCell] = sh.getRangeList([`R${rngRow}C${rngCol}`, `R${rngRow}C${otherCol}`])
      .getRanges().map(range => range.getValue());
      
    if ((cell == 'NON') || (otherCell == 'NON')) {

      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      sh.getRangeList([`C${rngRow}:G${rngRow}`, `L${rngRow}:N${rngRow}`, `P${rngRow}`, `U${rngRow}:W${rngRow}`])
        .getRanges().forEach(range => range.copyTo(dest.getRange(`${range.getA1Notation()[0]}7`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false))

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortSC()
    };
  };
};
```

This is working as per the stated condition:

> "Suivi Clients" tab to be "OUI" or "ANNULÉ" in the L AND U column so that the rows go from "Suivi Clients" to "Clients Finalisé"

AND

> Once a customer's row is in the "Clients Finalisé" tab, I would like that if I change the value of the L OR U column from "OUI" or "ANNULÉ" to "NON", the row goes back to the "Suivi Clients" tab

Add your other functions inside. Or check the dummy sheet you have provided I have added the full codes there. I have also tested it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I just added the complete code..

Comment: i have edited the posted answer. I have added the code for the 2nd condition to return it back to the "Suivi Clients" sheet. Add the other functions you have inside or just check the link for the dummy sheet you provided for the full code. Let me know if it's working as intended.

Comment: Everything works perfectly, thanks a lot Dan! I added to my answer the code that works..

Comment: Welcome! Glad to know it's resolved..